# System Recovery on a Virtual Win 10 PC

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, hyper-v, recovery-disk

I have a virtual Windows 10 PC on a VHDX. I use Windows Hyper-V to run the virtual machine.
Since last week I get this error when trying to start it:

[image: Error Code: 0xc000000e]

It says that i need to use recovery tools. Now, I know how to create / use those, however I am confused on how to use them using a virtual machine.

I can create a recovery disk and boot from that but then i could only recover the windows of the host machine, not the virtual one.

What can I do to fix this error on a virtual machine?

Comment: Why not just press `F1` to boot to WinRE?

Comment: does nothing. flickers for a quarter of a second and then shows the exact same error.

Answer (score 0):

You should run the recovery from the VM.

In the VM Settings, set the DVD/CD to the ISO file containing the boot media
for your Windows version. Under the BIOS section, Startup order, move the CD
entry to the top.

Booting now, you should get an option to boot from the ISO.
You might need to quickly hit some key.

Comment: Provided the DVD drive is placed at the top of the boot list under VM Settings > Firmware, it will auto-boot to the ISO upon VM startup

Comment: i will try this next time i am on the machine. thx a lot for the explanation.